# Posting to a Twitter account from a Rails 3 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter

I have an website that publishes news or blog items once a day.

I would like a news/blog item to be posted straight to the company Twitter account after it's posted.

A lot of the guides on the net seem to be regarding using the current_user's twitter username and I cannot seem to find one for my specific job.

How do I go about doing this? I have already logged into dev.twitter.com and got my token etc...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a gem for rails that is built to handle Twitter API: https://github.com/sferik/twitter

The process is quite simple, all you have to do is create a Twitter APP and get the APP_TOKEN and APP_SECRET along with your company's Twitter USER_TOKEN and USER_SECRET. After that you can configure the Twitter gem.

*config/initializers/twitter.rb:*

```
client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
    config.consumer_key = "YOUR_APP_CONSUMER_SECRET"
    config.consumer_secret = "YOUR_APP_CONSUMER_SECRET"
    config.access_token = "A_USER_ACCESS_TOKEN"
    config.access_token_secret = "A_USER_ACCESS_SECRET"
end
```

Once this is done, all you have to do is call the method "update" on the client you just created and the post will be made to the User's feed on twitter:

```
client.update("Article Lorem Ipsum...")
```

Just remember that the message length is limited to 140 chars.

Comment: In case you don't know how to proper install a gem. You just add `gem 'twitter'` to your _Gemfile_ and run `bundle install` on terminal.

Comment: Hope it works for you, feel free to send me a message if you're having any trouble.

Comment: I get undefined local variable or method `client' when doing it this way, any suggestions?

Comment: Found out I needed to set 'client' as a global variable: $client

Answer (score 0):

You can use the twitter gem: https://github.com/sferik/twitter

Once you install it and set your token etc. you can just do something like this in your article "publish" method:

```
Twitter.update(self.title)
```

or simply:

```
Twitter.update("Just published a new article.")
```

in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking simply how to post to Twitter, try using one of the Twitter API gems available.

http://sferik.github.io/twitter/ is one option you have.

From the docs: `Twitter.update("I'm tweeting with @gem!")`

However, if you're asking how you can grab the blog items once a day, and you have no means to duplicate that post, you can likely scrape the web page (though be sure to check their robots.txt first!). There are a lot of tools out there that can do this such as Selenium or Watir, but my personal preference is to use Mechanize for anything not involving Javascript.

From scraping you can store that message for later, and use the Twitter gem to post it using your credentials!

Comment: This isn't what I was after, but I'm definitely going to look into this - thank you!